# How can I optimize this vba loop code?

Tags: optimization, vba

Hi I wrote this code. but this code is very slow. How can I optimize this code?

```
Private Sub printItem(r, lastCol, objStream)
    FirstCol = 1

    Dim strFirst As String

    strFirst = CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1).Value)

    If strFirst = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

        objStream.WriteText "    <"
        objStream.WriteText "TagName"
        objStream.WriteText " "

        For c = FirstCol To lastCol

            data = CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c).Value)

            If LenB(Trim$(data)) > 0 Then
                objStream.WriteText g_AttributeName(c)
                objStream.WriteText "="""
                objStream.WriteText data
                objStream.WriteText """ "
            End If

        Next c

        objStream.WriteText "/>"

    objStream.WriteText vbNewLine
End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing stands out, except maybe you'd be better off reading the cell values into a variant array in one operation, instead of one-by-one.  How many columns is it typically reading, and is objStream a text file, or some other stream?  And what happens in g-AttributeName(). ?

Comment: VBA is interpreted. It's supposed to be useful, not fast. Also all those `WriteText` calls are going to cost you, though that depends on what `objStream` is writing to. A file will be faster than a console. Bottom line - I'm not sure you can do much better.

Comment: Slow as in how slow?  Slower than you expected, or so slow that it is stopping you from doing something?  As previously mentioned speed is not necesrrily VBA's forte.  And for things that are quick and dirty to write I accept slower performance

Comment: @Peter M: Word... But why go for a slow and dirty solution when a fast and equally dirty solution exists? Even with a certain amount of dirt, VBA can be plenty fast -- as long as you know where not to put the dirt.

Answer (score 4):

This is the likely reason why your code is slow: you are looping through cells. There is significant overhead to each communication between VBA and Excel sheet data, and this adds up when you refer to many cells one at a time.

Instead, you should load all your data at once into a `Variant` array, and then loop through that array, as shown below. This is significantly faster.

```
    Dim varData As Variant

    varData = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, FirstCol).Resize(1, lastCol - FirstCol + 1)

    For c = LBound(varData, 2) To UBound(varData, 2)

        data = CStr(varData(1, c))

        If LenB(Trim$(data)) > 0 Then
            ' etc.
        EndIf

    Next c
```

For further reading, have a look at this old but still relevant article: http://www.avdf.com/apr98/art_ot003.html